# Не сохраняет html selenium

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

def get_source_html(url):
    service = Service(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe')
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    driver.maximize_window()
    try:

        driver.get(url=url)
        time.sleep(3)  # Увеличьте задержку перед поиском элемента
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        find_more_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.e798o580.app-catalog-127qi1g.e1x8kbo0')
        actions.move_to_element(find_more_element).perform()
        with open('page.html', 'w') as f:
             f.write(driver.page_source)
    except Exception as _ex:
        print(_ex)
    finally:
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()

def main():
    get_source_html('https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/processory/?p=1')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

подскажите, что не так?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (**«почему этот код не работает?»**) должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**.

Comment: Вопросы
Метки
Закладки
Участники
Неотвеченные
Не сохраняет html selenium

Comment: Почему вы используете selenium устаревшей версии?